# Complex message and Masstransit de-serialization

Tags: .net, clr, json.net, ilmerge, masstransit

I publish a message in MT which has several Object-typed properties, as I don't know the type at compile time. When I receive the message in the consumer I see, that the Object-typed properties are populated with Newtonsoft JObject-instances. The JObject-Class resides in the ILMerged Newtonsoft.Json-assembly in Masstransit.dll. The JObject-Class in this assembly is marked internal. Whenever I try to cast the property-value to an JObject provided by a Nuget-Assembly of Newtonsoft.Json it fails.

So my questions are:

- What is the correct way to cast the property-value to JObject?
- Why does the cast fail? That means, what are the difficulties the clr has here?
- Can I get the raw, unserialized message-body in my consumer?

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot use JSON serialization if you are doing runtime typing on any message contracts.  If you want to do this, you'll require the use of the binary serializer.

You cannot access the raw, unserialized message-body; if the message cannot be deserialized, then no user code is called.

Having any types marked internal will not allow us to deserialize the message. A constructor cannot be called, thus no object creation. I'm not sure the binary serializer will allow you to get around this limitation, not something I've tested.

If you have other questions, you're welcomed to join the mailing list as well, https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/masstransit-discuss.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. But unfortunately even the message-types bundled with the latest Masstransit-NuGet package (heartbeat, subscription, etc.) don't seem to work with the BinarySerializer. They're not decorated with the Serializable attribute.

Comment: Please submit an issue (or better yet a pull request) to get them decorated properly so binary serialization works.

Comment: Develop would be a good start. Chris was merging in a bunch of stuff today, so there's likely a new release before too long. If you pick the wrong branch we can always cherry pick it in, so it's not a huge deal.

Answer (score 2):

As one of the creators of MassTransit, if you're including

```
public object MyMessageProperty { get; set; }
```

In your message contract, you're doing it wrong. Leverage the strongly typed publishing features of the framework instead of doing your own dynamic dispatch on top of the dispatching already being done by the publish/subscribe system inside MT.

Comment: As you see, I mentioned in my solution I know, that is not the way you intended to the polymorphic dispatch to be used. That said, I have messages with combinations of types. It would be quite a number of messages to represent all combinations in a typed way.

Comment: Yes, there are quite a few messages, but inheritance and interfaces are supported, so you can really do more interesting things by leveraging types. You can start to observe events, look at parts of the message without having to (x is Y) everywhere. It really is the best way to do it, be explicit and deliberate vs. chaos. This is critical when the code leaves your mind and starts being used by others.

Answer (score 0):

My above described problem probably arose just out of a misconception of my messaging system. But I found a nasty workaround to convert the nested JObjects to the right domain objects:

```
protected bool TryConvertJObjectToDtoOfType<T>(Object jObjectInDisguise, out T dto)
     where T: BpnDto
{
    try
    {
         if (jObjectInDisguise.GetType().Name != typeof(JObject).Name)
             throw new ArgumentException("Object isn't a JObject", "jObjectInDisguise");

        var json = jObjectInDisguise.ToString();
        var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings()
        {
            MissingMemberHandling = MissingMemberHandling.Error
        };

        dto = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(json, settings);
        return true;
    } catch
    {
        dto = null;
        return false;
    }
}
```